# Syntax error (missing operator) in query

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I'm trying to add a review to a site I'm building. As the content of the review is split into 3 tables I am trying to execute 3 inserts into the database for the one review. The page displays when I run it so I know most of it is working but when I click the submit button I get a:

```
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '3')'' error message.
```

It's saying that problem is in this line of code:

```
Line 86:         dbInsert.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

This is the code I have for this section:

```
Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO MovieReviews (MovieID, MReviewID, ReviewerType, ReviewDate, UserID) "
    sql = sql & " VALUES ('" & movID & "','" & review_id & "','" & 2 & "','" & Date.Now & "'," & uID & "')'"
    Dim sql2 As String = "INSERT INTO MReviewRatings (MReviewID, ValueForMoney, ActingAbility, SpecialEffects, Plot, Total) "
    sql2 = sql2 & " VALUES ('" & movID & "','" & moneyStar(moneyStarRating) & "','" & actingStar(actingStarRating) & "','" & effectsStar(effectStarRating) & "','" & plotStar(plotStarRating) & "','" & totalStar(avg) & "')'"
    Dim sql3 As String = "INSERT INTO MReviewTexts (MReviewID, ReviewText) "
    sql3 = sql3 & " VALUES ('" & review_id & "','" & txtReviewText.Text & "')'"
    dbInsert.CommandText = sql
    dbInsert.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    dbInsert.Connection = aConnection

    dbInsert2.CommandText = sql2
    dbInsert2.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    dbInsert2.Connection = aConnection
    dbInsert3.CommandText = sql3
    dbInsert3.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    dbInsert3.Connection = aConnection
    dbInsert.ExecuteNonQuery()
    dbInsert2.ExecuteNonQuery()
    dbInsert3.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

I'm not sure what is causing the issue. Would anyone know how I can get the review to insert into the database?

Comment: if I were you, I'd log out the value of sql and look at it to determine the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra single quote at the end of your statements.

At the moment the string will result in something like...

```
insert into (x,y,z) values ('a','b','c')'
```

Instead of the line being like...

```
sql = sql & " VALUES ('" & movID .... uID & "')'"
```

You should have (note the missing `'`)...

```
sql = sql & " VALUES ('" & movID .... uID & "')"
```

---

As a side note, if your columns are numeric based, you don't need to place the value within a single quotes.

You should also look at trying to prevent [SQL Injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) by use the [stored procedures](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/160/sql-server-stored-procedure/)

Comment: Thank you freefaller. I probably should have seen that

Comment: You're welcome @user1850189. Although my answer does answer your specific question, I would thoroughly recommend you implement the answer suggested by NYCdotNet

Answer (score 1):

By implementing your code in this way, you are exposing yourself to SQL injection attacks as freefaller has noted.

You would be much better off writing your queries as such:

```
Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO MovieReviews (MovieID, MReviewID, ReviewerType, ReviewDate, UserID) " & _
    " VALUES (@movID,@review_id,@reviewerType,@timestamp,@userid)"
dbInsert.CommandText = sql
dbInsert.CommandType = CommandType.Text
dbInsert.Connection = aConnection
dbInsert.Parameters.Add(New SQLParameter("@movID",movID))
dbInsert.Parameters.Add(New SQLParameter("@review_id",review_id ))
dbInsert.Parameters.Add(New SQLParameter("@reviewerType",2))
dbInsert.Parameters.Add(New SQLParameter("@timestamp",Date.Now))
dbInsert.Parameters.Add(New SQLParameter("@userid",uID))
dbInsert.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

The remaining queries can get similar treatment.  This change not only protects you from SQL injection attacks but it also makes your data access layer code much more manageable.

Comment: I didn't have time to go into this much detail, but I have recommended to the OP that they follow your suggestion. +1

Answer (score 0):

This line looks like its missing a single quote near the end (just before `uID`):

```
sql = sql & " VALUES ('" & movID & "','" & review_id & "','" & 2 & "','" & Date.Now & "'," & uID & "')'"
```

s/b:

```
sql = sql & " VALUES ('" & movID & "','" & review_id & "','" & 2 & "','" & Date.Now & "','" & uID & "')'"
```

Comment: Or shouldn't have the very last `'` before the `)` if UID is an `int`

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that all the fileds are Varchar...

```
Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO MovieReviews (MovieID, MReviewID, ReviewerType, ReviewDate, UserID) "
sql = sql & " VALUES ('" & movID & "','" & review_id & "','" & 2 & "','" & Date.Now & "','" & uID & "')"
Dim sql2 As String = "INSERT INTO MReviewRatings (MReviewID, ValueForMoney, ActingAbility, SpecialEffects, Plot, Total) "
sql2 = sql2 & " VALUES ('" & movID & "','" & moneyStar(moneyStarRating) & "','" & actingStar(actingStarRating) & "','" & effectsStar(effectStarRating) & "','" & plotStar(plotStarRating) & "','" & totalStar(avg) & "')"
Dim sql3 As String = "INSERT INTO MReviewTexts (MReviewID, ReviewText) "
sql3 = sql3 & " VALUES ('" & review_id & "','" & txtReviewText.Text & "')"
```